# R hist(): how to set proper bins

Tags: r

I'm trying to obtain an hist plot on a set of numeric data, but getting "some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x' " as error.

My data range is:

`> range(width(myseq2))
[1]   350 16739`

and my command is:

`hist(width(myseq2), breaks=c(350, seq(500, 16800, 150)), col="blue", ylim = c(0,40000))`

meaning that I want bins of 150, spanning from the minimal to maximal values of my data.

I don't get what's wrong..
Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: Likely you have a problem with your data. Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Preparing a MVCE will likely help you to solve your own problem. Also, you should include your exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range gets truncated at the top end because it doesn't divide evenly.  The 16739 value doesn't get a bin.

```
range(c(350, seq(500, 16800, 150)))  
# [1]   350 16700
```

Just expand the range, for example:

```
hist(width(myseq2), breaks=c(350, seq(500, 16850, 150)), col="blue", ylim = c(0,40000))
```